# cookies store form elements

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have setup the following: http://webhostlet.com/POP.htm

I want to have a "save" button, which will, when pressed, remember the value of every form element on the page. (checkboxes, text boxes). Or maybe even just remember the values automatically without a "save" button. I have looked it up but cookies are confusing the hell out of me.... I dont even know whether its better for me in this case to use  php or javascript, php looks simpler but you can only set them before html elements... which complicates it... =/

say I have 13 checkboxes, with ID's "rama", "ramb", "ramc" etc etc.... How would I rmemeber those and load them nexttime the user visits?

And the same goes for text boxes, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your html code part

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the form, use jQuery.

```
$('yourform').serialize();
```

Then use cookie to store the serialized string.

Comment: Thanks, although im still a little unsure on how to utilise that. I have never done anything with cookies before, once the form is serialised... how do i get the form to save and load as mentioned above? Thanks